# Can I explicitly define a getter without using literals?

Tags: javascript

I know I can define a getter/setter using

```
let myObject = {
  get myProp(){ return this.myOtherProp; }
}
```

But how can I add a getter directly like how we do it in value properties

```
myObject.myProp = "value";
```

I know we can use `Object.defineProperty(myObject, 'myProp', {})` or perhaps just make our own anonymous function `myObject.myProp = function(){}`.

But is there another way?

Comment: `Object.defineProperty` it is. Not sure what you're asking for since you already know?

Comment: I was thinking if it is possible more directly without using `Object.defineProperty` or without defining custom getter methods.

Comment: Are you asking for a syntax like `myObject[get myProp] = function(){}`? I don’t think there is such a thing.

Comment: Something like that yeah.

Comment: Would be nice syntax, but yeah, `Object.defineProperty` is the only way to do this. You can use `Object.defineProperties` to assign several at once, if you want to make it any shorter.

Comment: Alright thanks guys.

Comment: @Merigold you should submit a proposal to TC39 for `object[get property]` and `object[set property]`, I would totally be on board for that

Comment: @Xufox was the one who thought of the syntax though!